# Add a relationship Neo4j based upon a condition

Tags: neo4j

I have 2 node Labels : Account , Transactions.

```
MATCH (n:Account)
RETURN n
```

returns me 4 accounts with this property's:

```
accountName RAHUL RAINA
id  16294736
accountName SAVINGS ACCOUNT - RES
id  16294732
accountName VISA GOLD
id  16294492
accountName SBCHQ-GEN-PUB-IND-NONRURAL-INR
id  16294488
```

Transactions is like this :

```
MATCH (n:Transaction) 
RETURN n LIMIT 5
```

and this returns me :

```
id  133817384
description ATM07JUN15 NFS 11:38:44A96103218ATM
postedDate  6/8/2015
transactionDate 6/8/2015
accountId   16294732
id  133815940
description TO TRANSFER INB Tinyowl Technology Privat
postedDate  6/8/2015
transactionDate 6/8/2015
accountId   16294488
```

I want to make a link between these two node labels or a relationship (I am not sure what it is called ) when the `transaction.accountId == account.id`

How do I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MATCH (a:Account), (t:Transaction)
WHERE a.id = t.accountId
CREATE (t)-[:FROM_ACCOUNT]->(a)
```

Comment: Actually if you have an index on :Account(id) this one will be more efficient on large datasets: `MATCH (t:Transaction)
MATCH (a:Account) 
WHERE a.id = t.accountId
CREATE (t)-[:FROM_ACCOUNT]->(a)`